# MongoDB Database

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

well... I don't know anything about not relational data base and I wanna know if the following script is correct.

The data base it's developed for obtain management of users and schedules, (The schedules are related with a professor and a classroom). The classrooms have a code and they can be commented and rated by users.

```
db.user.insert({
      //Can be 6 o 10 digits
      _id : 201309,
      name : {
        First : "Fernando",
        Last : "Sarmiento"
      },
      area : 2,
      account : {
          email : "email@google.com",
          password : "Password1!",
          level : 0
      },
      status : {
          status : "Active",
          Date : 17-01-2016 
      },
      //Can be null
      comment : "I like cereal",
})
```

-

```
db.schedule.insert({
    _id: ObjectId(),
    day : "Lunes",
    hour : 13 : 00,
    finalHour : 14 : 00,
    teacher : {
        $ref : "user",
        $id  : $id.user 
    },
    classroom : {
        $ref : "classroom",
        $id : $id.classrom
    } 
})
```

-

```
db.classroom.insert({
    _id : ObjectId(),
    name : "Software Development",
    comment : "classrom 3",
    //Can take values from 0 to 5 
    score : $avg(userScore),

    code : [
        {
            code : "ABCDEF123456",
            user : [{
                $ref : "user",
                $id : $id.user
            }]
        }
    ],

    post : [
        {
            post : "I like the classrom :)",
            date : 17-01-2016,
            user : [{
                $ref : "user",
                $id : $id.user
            }]
        }
    ],

    userScore : [{
        score : 4.5,
        user : [{
                $ref : "user",
                $id : $id.user
            }]
    }] 
})
```

Thanks! :3